# react-query selector or manipulate cache direclty

Tags: react-query

currently I am working with react-query. I have a api endpoint that provide me a list of all patients with details.

```
useQuery([“patients”], getPatients)
```

That query store all my patients in cache in an array.

However in some cases I need to fetch by single patient and at that time all patients haven’t been loaded yet. Since getPatients and getSinglePatient have the same data structure, what is the proper way to save all patients in cache by its id, to later update a single patient and only invalidate for that single patient???

Can I use selector to choose that single patient and just invalidate this query? If so, how can I create the proper query key to store that patient using selector?

Or do I have to manually map the result from backend and store in cache by id?

Then just use getSinglePatient?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to identify your patient from getSinglePatient would be something along these lines

`useQuery([“patient”, {patient id here}], getSinglePatient)`

This will create a unique entry in the cache for each patient you get by id.

Comment: Yes, but doing this I will have duplicated data. Because that patient could be in the [patients] query and [patients, id]

Comment: That is true, but from a frontend perspective you want to rely on your api's and backend to handle any data manipulation, or updates. So if you update a single patient you would refetch that patient from the api after the update is complete. Same with multiple patients, if you want to edit a single patient instead of extracting that patient from your patient list you would want to fetch that single patient.

Comment: @limaho33 there is no "normalized cache" in react query so yes, the data will be duplicated. It will be stored per resource. Two api endpoints = two cache entries. This is a very simple concept that will get you very far, without any magic. You can also use `initialData` to pre-populate the detail cache with data from the list cache, this is in the docs: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/initial-query-data#initial-data-from-cache

Comment: Thanks @TkDodo using initialData + initialDataUpdatedAt is the best way to go. Thanks again